# How to draw square using area in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to draw a square using area in d3.js? Is it even possible to do that?

My code:

```js
var data = [
  {x: 0, y: 0},
  {x: 5, y: 0},
  {x: 0, y: 5},
  {x: 5, y: 5},
];

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 6]).range([25, 175]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,20]).range([175, 25]);

var area = d3.area()
  .x(d => xScale(d.x))
  .y0(yScale(0))
  .y1(d => yScale(d.y));

d3.select("#demo1")
.append("path")
.attr("d", area(data))
.attr("fill", "red")
.attr("stroke", "black");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="demo1" width="200" height="200"></svg>
```

Result of this code:
[image]

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a square using `d3.area()` using the following points:

```js
var points = [
    { xpoint: 0, ypoint: 200 },
    { xpoint: 200, ypoint: 200 }
];
```

```js
var points = [
    { xpoint: 0, ypoint: 200 },
    { xpoint: 200, ypoint: 200 }
];

var Gen = d3.area()
    .x((p) => p.xpoint)
    .y0((p) => 0)
    .y1((p) => p.ypoint);

d3.select("#gfg")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", Gen(points))
    .attr("fill", "green")
    .attr("stroke", "black");
```

```css
svg { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="gfg" width="200" height="200"></svg>
```

---

For the shape in [your image](https://ibb.co/sJ4rLhC), try the following points:

```js
var points = [
    { xpoint: 0, ypoint: 0 },
    { xpoint: 100, ypoint: 100 },
    { xpoint: 125, ypoint: 125 },
    { xpoint: 150, ypoint: 175 },
    { xpoint: 190, ypoint: 175 },
    { xpoint: 150, ypoint: 100 },
    { xpoint: 50, ypoint: 0 },
];
```

```js
var points = [
    { xpoint: 0, ypoint: 0 },
    { xpoint: 100, ypoint: 100 },
    { xpoint: 125, ypoint: 125 },
    { xpoint: 150, ypoint: 175 },
    { xpoint: 190, ypoint: 175 },
    { xpoint: 150, ypoint: 100 },
    { xpoint: 50, ypoint: 0 },
];

var Gen = d3.area()
    .x((p) => p.xpoint)
    .y0((p) => 0)
    .y1((p) => p.ypoint);

d3.select("#gfg")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", Gen(points))
    .attr("fill", "green")
    .attr("stroke", "black");
```

```css
svg { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="gfg" width="200" height="200"></svg>
```

Comment: Maybe you know how to create such figure [link](https://ibb.co/sJ4rLhC)

Comment: Please see my edit with a second snippet.